# Delphi chat dont send message on some ip

Tags: delphi, tcp, delphi-7

I want to make simple Delphi chat. I use Tcp/IP client and server socket.
When i try to send message on my computer i getting error 10060.

To simplify if my computer is "comp1" and other computer in network is "comp2"
on both computer i set same port (9096 for example) on comp1 i set ip of "comp2" and on "comp2" i set ip address of "comp1".

Ports are open in firewall..

"Comp1" is my personal and have dynamic ip address and router(maybe problem is router?)
"Comp2" is other computer that don't have router and have static address.

When i try to send message from "Comp1" to "Comp2" i get message on "Comp2" and i don't have problem, if i try to send message from "Comp2" to "Comp1" i not get message and for few seconds i get message about 10060 error.

When i try in local network with local ip addresses program work.

Is problem router or something else?

Thanks

Comment: Wild guess: Is IPv6 enabled? If so, try disabling it and do your trials again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't a Delphi issue, but a network configuration issue. The problem is your router receives the message from Comp2 but doesn't know what to do with it. You need to enable port forwarding on your router to forward port 9096 (or whatever TCP port you are using) on to Comp1. You'll also need to configure the router to reserve the same address for your Comp1 PC, otherwise the program will stop working if the PC gets assigned a different IP address when it's rebooted.